# trying to change the attribute of input element and replace it with hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a small modification where on the selection of YES/NO from a Dropdown will run the following code

```
$(document).on('#is_taxable','change',function() {
    var data = $(this).val();
    alert(data);
    if(data == 'true') {
        $("#tax_authority_id").attr('type','hidden');
        $("#tax_exemption_id").attr('type','hidden');
        $("Tax Authority is hidden because it is not required when taxable is 'YES'").insertAfter("label['for=inputtax_authority_id']");
        $("Tax Exemption is hidden because it is not required when taxable is 'YES'").insertAfter("label['for=tax_exemption_id']");
    }else {
        $("#tax_authority_id").attr('type','text');
        $("#tax_exemption_id").attr('type','text');
        $("#tax_id_value").attr('type','hidden');
        $("Tax Value is hidden because it is not required when taxable is 'NO'").insertAfter("label['for=inputtaxitem']");
    }
});
```

I am trying to change the attr of the Input fields to hidden so at east they are still there while the form needs it when submitted to server side, i cannot disable them

How can i fix, it just does nothing to change it, am i missing something here

Answer (score 0):

Use `.hide()` or `.show()` instead. like

```
$("#tax_authority_id").hide();
```

---

```
$("#tax_authority_id").show();
```

---

Your code

```
$(document).on('#is_taxable','change',function() {
    var data = $(this).val();
    alert(data);
    if(data == 'true') {
        $("#tax_authority_id").hide();
        $("#tax_exemption_id").hide();
        $("Tax Authority is hidden because it is not required when taxable is 'YES'").insertAfter("label['for=inputtax_authority_id']");
        $("Tax Exemption is hidden because it is not required when taxable is 'YES'").insertAfter("label['for=tax_exemption_id']");
    }else {
        $("#tax_authority_id").show();
        $("#tax_exemption_id").show();
        $("#tax_id_value").hide();
        $("Tax Value is hidden because it is not required when taxable is 'NO'").insertAfter("label['for=inputtaxitem']");
    }
});
```

Comment: if i hide and show, will that form will still be available in the server side processing, i was changing because enabling them requires a validation code to be added, a jquery validation plugin code `data*` attributes code like `data-rule-required`

Comment: @Initiater `.hide` is equivalent to css `display:none`. The elements will be send in the request

Comment: okay i take it as you say, but how do i add validation if its set to display as show

Comment: its gonna use jquery validation plugin

Comment: means I didnt get you ?